# Remove part of string

Tags: php, string

```
<?php
 $test = 'marke=' . $_GET["marke"] . '&farbe=' . $_GET["farbe"]. '&groesse=' . $_GET["groesse"];
?>

 <?php
echo $test;
?>
```

echo would be: marke=diesel&farbe=blau&groesse=xl

How can i remove &farbe=blau from $test ?

Comment: how about just not adding it in the first place? get rid of the `&farbe=' . $_GET['farbe']. '` part

Comment: that would be too much work with over 5 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to reliably parse and create query-strings (which also takes care of nasty url-encoding issues):

```
// You could probably have created $test with:
// $test = http_build_query($_GET);
parse_str($test,$values);
unset($values['farbe']);
$test = http_build_query($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [a regular expression with `preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)? Off the top of my head, try something like:

```
preg_replace('/&farbe=.+?&/','',$test);
```

Comment: nice that works too but i can only check one answer as accepted ^^

Comment: No problem at all - mark whichever one answered your question better, quicker, with more documentation, and so on. There's rarely only *one* way to do it, after all.